# accents not working in subsubsection header

Tags: sectioning, accents

I have to reference some products of Cadence Design Systems. I run into a problem when I try to write 'Cadence' with a macron above 'a'.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{cochineal}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{C\={a}dence SimVision}
C\={a}dence SimVision

\end{document}
```

The accent is rendered differently when it appears in the subsubsection header,[image: wrongly placed macron]

but is exactly the way I want it in the normal text. What am I doing wrong here? Is the custom subsubsection formatting incorrect?

Comment: your example produces the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \titleformat` Can you edit the question to have an error free example. (actually just removing is enough, I'll do it)

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, I think it's a problem with `cochineal`: if you add `\bfseries` in the text (not in the heading) you observe the same problem. I'm not sure whether it's a problem with the font or with the package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the O.P. forgot to load `titlesec` in his/her post.

Comment: @Bernard I know (but it's simpler to debug without the extra packages) as you say it looks like a font error

Comment: I filed a bug report to the maintainer of `cochineal`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, as Bernard said, I forgot to include the titlesec package. But anyway, thanks for the edit.

Comment: The package `cochineal` has been updated and the bug removed. See the entry in the TeX Live repository at http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=48917 and on CTAN at https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=cochineal [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ccp3.png) of the output with the updated version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a bug now solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{cochineal}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\textbf{C\={a}dence SimVision}
C\={a}dence SimVision

\end{document}
```

You see the same with the above, it appears to be an error in the bold font not a problem in the tex macros.

A workaround might be to move the accent "by hand"

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{cochineal}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}

%\showoutput
\begin{document}

\textbf{C\rlap{\kern-.45em\={}}adence SimVision}
C\={a}dence SimVision

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. However, I don't quite understand the code. Could you explain what is happening here?

Comment: @34.5 the `\rlap{...}` makes a zero width box so any space adjustments don't affect the surrounding text, then inside that I put `\={}` so having the accent over "nothing" then the `\kern-4.5em` was just moving it "by eye" to be over the `a`.  Note that if the font is fixed that manual shift will do the wrong thing and you would need to remove this workaround and go back to the original version.